# C# Fast Matrix Manipulation

Tags: c#, matlab, loops, matrix

Having a matrix like this in C#

```
double[,] M
```

I would like to get the same fast manipulation of its content as Matlab does. In particular, having this code in Matlab:

```
for i = 1:N
    M(i, 1:i) = 1;
```

I would like to have its equivalent in C# without a second loop. I'm not sure about this, but as far as I know, Matlab uses a process called Vectorization for this line `M(i, 1:i) = 1`, which is faster than me implementing a for loop from 1 to i setting each cell to 1. Maybe I'm wrong, please correct me.

So how can achieve a fast manipulation of matrices in C# like Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution is to use a matrix library like [math.net numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) for matrix operations.

Comment: hm, I see ... I thought there is something simpler just to bypass a for loop, something C# native libraries already have. Will this library make this line M(i, 1:i) = 1 actually faster than a for loop? Or is more for providing multiple handy small algorithms and make the code syntax more abstract.

Comment: Most of these packages are wrappers for libraries written in C or Fortran. If I'm reading the docs correctly, you have three choices for the underlying linear algebra engine: GotoBLAS, Intel MKL, or AMD ACML. GoBLAS is non-commercial. MKL is commercial, but has the distinction of being the fastest matrix library on Intel processors. And I found this disclaimer: http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/docs/Matrix.html#Context-Linear-Algebra

Comment: I was on the exact same page reading :). Thank you, I think this approach will lead to the right answer for my question.

Comment: So using this math.net ... what is the syntax to write this line M(i, 1:i) = 1 without the for loop :( ?

Comment: I hope this looks right ... 
M.SetSubMatrix(i, 1, m.Dense(1,i,1)); 
where m.Dense creates a matrix of 1 row, i columns all with value 1